# Update a MySQL db via link in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

What I am trying to do is call a php class to update a connected mysql db, without changing the page.  I am thinking I can do it with Ajax, but I am not certain.  I have seen tons of examples using forms, but I am looking for a simple `<a href="#">link</a>`.

Comment: call a ajax function on clicking the link.

Comment: Ajax is the way to go, here's a simplified example in jQuery: `$('#elID').click(function(){$.get('urlToChangeDB');return false});`. If you can be a little clearer we can help you better.

Comment: Do you want to *send* an update to mysql, or update the database itself (both are possible, but have different implementations)

Comment: Just be careful that your clickable link doesn't point at "DROP DATABASE something_very_critical". The first person/spider to hit your site will trash everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on Khez's comment, using jquery you could use something like:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="PathToJquery"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready (function ()
{
    $('#elID').click(function ()
    {
        $.get('urlToChangeDB?variable=value');
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="#" id="elID">Link</a>
</body>
</html>
```

You will need to inlude the jquery libray

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to use some Ajax, probably through JQuery. A simple example would be to take a form like

Form.php

```
<form id="ratingform" name="ratingform">        
    <input type="text" id="id" name="id" />

    <input type="text" id="rating" name="rating" />

    <input type="submit" id="loginsubmit" name="loginsubmit" value="Submit!" />
</form>
```

Then link it with some JQuery to intercept the form, and send it to a PHP file

JQuery.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#ratingform").submit(function(event) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "rate.php",
            data: $('#ratingform').serialize(),
                datatype: "json",
            success: function(data){
                var ret = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                    if(ret.result == "true")
                        // Success
                    else
                        // Failure
            }
    });
    event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Then, create the PHP file to interpret it

rate.php

```
$stmt = $sql->dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO `rating` (`ID`, `Rating`) VALUES (:id, :rating)");

$stmt->bindValue(':id', $_POST['id']);
$stmt->bindValue(':rating', $_POST['rating']);

$result = $stmt->execute();

echo json_encode(array('result' => "{$result}"));

die();
```

Essentially, the JQuery intercepts the form action and cancels it, then uses `serialize()` to package up the data and set it to `rate.php` as POST data. Then `rate.php` handles it as a normal POST submission, and `echo()`s a JSON encoded result of either "true" or "false", depending on whether or no the SQL query was successful, which is sent back to the JQuery script. The JQuery interprets the JSON object, then performs actions based on whether or not the SQL Query was successful.